# Is there a C# collection that can be set by index and string and allows duplicate keys?

Tags: c#, php, arrays, dictionary, collections

The closest I could find is `NameValueCollection`.

With that class I can add duplicate keys and can get by string and index.

However, even though I can assign by string. I cannot assign by index since its set to ready only.

```
NameValueCollection data = new NameValueCollection();

data.Add("foo", "");

string foo = data["foo"]; // valid

foo = data[0]; // valid

data["foo"] = "abc"; // valid

data[0] = "abc"; // invalid
```

I want something similar to an array variable in PHP.

Comment: In PHP, an array is implemented as an **ordered hashmap**. It's a slight extension to the typical hashmap structure by allowing string keys to be hashed to integers and integers to remain as keys, then all integer values are `mod(sizeof(array))`. Then collisions are resolved by a *doubly linked list*. When a collision occurs, you traverse the doubly linked list and the actual key is checked from the bucket to ensure it's the right one. You can read more about its implementation [here](https://blog.ircmaxell.com/2012/03/phps-source-code-for-php-developers.html). It's a 4 part blog post.

Comment: @Sherif that would be similar to OrderedDictionary, but that class doesn't allow duplicate keys

Comment: neither do PHP arrays. A PHP array key **must** be unique.

Comment: Can you just use `data[data.Keys[0]] = "abc";`?

Comment: @Sherif yes, thats why I mentioned its similar, but not exact. It needs to support duplicate keys.

Comment: @JohnWu that would work, but I would prefer not to require that if possible. Edit: nevermind. That won't work because of duplicate keys.

Comment: `data["foo"] = "abc";` what does this do if there are 2 "foos"

Comment: @MichaelRandall Currently NameValueCollection's add function appends the string using a comma which is not what I want. I want it to access the first column that matches that key. I can make it myself, but I'd prefer to use a pre-existing class if it already exists.

Comment: There is nothing in the BLC  anywhere close to this. There is `ListDictionary` however doesn't support duplicates... You are going to have to roll your own

Comment: @MichaelRandall Alrighty

Comment: how do you want to get\set by key if you have duplicate keys?

Comment: To be honest, I don't think that what you're after here is the ability to have duplicate keys, but rather the ability to store more than one value under the same key. This could be achieved with a simple map -> map structure. A hashmap that just gives you a list of values for a given key, each item assumed to be a duplicate of that key. Would that not satisfy your requirements?

Comment: @Sherif this is for a CSV reader. I want to be able to access the column values by their name as a shortcut, but also be able to access them by index when there was no header provided or if there was duplicate names in the header. I resolved this by making a List of KeyValuePair objects and using the string and int getters and setters overrides on the class.

Comment: But CSVs are not just Key/Value pairs. They're precise vectors made up of column/row coordinates. So a map -> map sounds about right for this use case.

Comment: @Sherif each column is a key value pair and it processes only one row at a time. This solution works fine for what I need. Your map to a map wouldn't store the correct index/offset of the column.